# Google Chrome is not allowing website login in IFRAME

Tags: html, google-chrome, iis, iframe, asp.net-identity

I want to open a website in my another site using iframe, but in google chrome it's not allow me to login into this site.
I have checked in other site it's working fine and I am able to login into that site.

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" allow="geolocation *;" src="http://ts2.techstern.com/" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" style="width:100%; height:700px; border:none;"></iframe>
```

The login feature is working fine with other browser but not working in google chrome browser.

Comment: look at this, hope this work for you
https://support.google.com/sites/thread/4372719?hl=en

Comment: already tried, not working.